# How to query all pdbs in Oracle 19c with container user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here the steps  after i connected with SQLPLUS on CDB$ROOT

```
> CREATE USER  c##SOMMONITOR IDENTIFIED BY SOM;
> GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##SOMMONITOR;
> grant select on v_$pdbs to c##SOMMONITOR container=all;
```

when i connect with SYSTEM user and run the below query

```
select dbid, con_id, name from v$pdbs; 

>  940078223    2   PDB$SEED
> 248774507 3   PRODPDB
> 428725798 4   PRODPDB2
```

i get all pluggable databases as result....

but same query doesnt show anything with c##SOMMONITOR....

i am trying to get all pluggable databases list with normal user on container database...